# Keep a battery iOS widget updated

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

i'm working on a battery widget but have problems updating the battery level
often enough. I Would love to update the widget every time the battery percentage changes. But from all the reading i have done, this looks to be impossible. I tried requesting a new timeline both every 5 min and every 15 min with no luck. I see some apps on the AppStore have a battery indicator and it updates quite often. Any clues to have they accomplishes this? I see some people  talking about using background fetch. That can't be the best way? I have included my code, maybe i have implemented it wrong?
Tanks for any feedback on this!

Provider

```
struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date())
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date())
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        let currentDate = Date()
        let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 15, to: currentDate)

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [SimpleEntry(date: currentDate)], policy: .after(newDate!))
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

BatteryWidgetEntryView

```
struct BatteryWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(Int(Self.battery * 100))")
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
    
    static let battery: Float = {
        UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
        let batteryLvl = UIDevice.current.batteryLevel
        return batteryLvl
    }()
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to access the value for the battery level inside the Widget. You should be accessing it in the timeline provider and passing it to your widget. Widgets are static and must rely on information being passed to them. So update your SimpleEntry to take Float and a Date, and you should be able to get it to update. Here are some Widget Examples to look at https://github.com/pawello2222/WidgetExamples

Comment: @Fredlnn did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from the Widget, you have to reload the timeline from the host app. Host app to monitor the battery status and call

```
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "com.mybattery.widget")
```

To trigger the reload for the widget.

Comment: I would have to do this when the app is in the background then. That wont give me much reliability?

Comment: @FredInn True, I can't think of anything to read battery status reliably for normal apps. Maybe it is possible to implement using VOIP or audio playing background mode but it could get rejected from app review.

Comment: Yeah, i can't risk that. Thank you for the input. I will have to do some more research i guess.